# Select query does not give all rows

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a table with 9 records.
When I run `SELECT * FROM table;` in my VB.Net I only get 6 from the 9 records.
When I run the query in 'DB Browser' an SQLite viewer I get them all.
Here is my code:

```vb
    Dim SQLconn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    SQLconn.ConnectionString = connstring

    If SQLconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLconn.Close()
    Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand
    Dim SQLdr As SQLiteDataReader
    Dim SQLstr As String

    SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM SignedEvent;"

    SQLconn.Open()
    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLconn
    SQLcmd.CommandText = SQLstr
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
    SQLcmd.Dispose()
    While SQLdr.Read()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SQLdr("TotalTicketCounter").ToString)
    End While

    SQLdr.Close()
    SQLconn.Close()
    SQLconn.Dispose()
```

Comment: Are you sure your db browser is looking at the same sqlite database?  I don't see why your query would not get some records.

Comment: You are assigning your connection string twice. Which is it, connection or constring?

Comment: I  removed the second connection string.

Comment: The thing is there is a service running in the background who adds records to the database (POS system) I can't stop this service and all the new records that are added I can't see in my query result. It's like the database is locked for other ussers and so it gives an old snapshot of the database... Very Strange.